# Calculate $\frac{a_{1}}{3}+\frac{a_{2}}{5}+\frac{a_{3}}{7}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{4013}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is a system of linear equations whose coefficient matrix is similar to Hilbert's matrix, and I feel that this problem can be calculated by our own hands, not using apps (MMA MATLAB), or the laws in it can be found.

\begin{aligned}
&\frac{a_{1}}{2}+\frac{a_{2}}{3}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{2007}=\frac{4}{3} . \\
&\frac{a_{1}}{3}+\frac{a_{2}}{4}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{2008}=\frac{4}{5} . \\
&\frac{a_{1}}{4}+\frac{a_{2}}{5}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{2009}=\frac{4}{7} . \\
&\ldots \ldots \\
&\frac{a_{1}}{2007}+\frac{a_{2}}{2008}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{4012}=\frac{4}{4013}.
 \end{aligned}

The question is
$$\frac{a_{1}}{3}+\frac{a_{2}}{5}+\frac{a_{3}}{7}+\cdots+\frac{a_{2006}}{4013}=?
 $$

Comment: @N Why do you believe that this solution can be calculated by hand?

Comment: Ax=b, the question is b^T * x, so I guess it can be calculated by hand. I am not sure, I guess. And if the question is a1+a2+a3+...+a2006, I think we should use Mathematica for calculations  directly.

Comment: The matrix is known as Hilbert's matrix whose inverse matrix can be expressed explictly. However, I have problem summing the terms up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I am working with hand and paper, so this may contain mistakes in the calculations. However, the method works)*

Consider the rational function $$ F(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{2006} \frac{a_i}{X+i}$$

By definition of the $a_i$'s, one has, for every $j \in [1,2006]$,

$$F(j)= \frac{4}{2j+1}$$

Hence, the polynomial $\displaystyle{P(X) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{2006}(X+i) \right) F(X)}$ is a polynomial of degree $2005$ which satisfies, for every $j \in [1, 2006]$,
$$P(j) = \frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{4}{2j+1}$$

By Lagrange's interpolation, one has
$$P(X) = \sum_{j=1}^{2006} \left(\frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{4}{2j+1} \right)\prod_{i = 1\\ i \neq j}^{2006} \frac{X-i}{j-i}$$

In particular, one has

\begin{align*} P \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) &= \sum_{j=1}^{2006} \frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{4}{2j+1} \prod_{i = 1\\ i \neq j}^{2006} \frac{\frac{1}{2}-i}{j-i}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2006} \frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{4}{(2j+1)2^{2005}} \prod_{i = 1\\ i \neq j}^{2006} \frac{1-2i}{j-i}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2006} \frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{4}{2j+1}  \frac{4012 !(-1)^{2007-j}}{2^{4011} 2006 !(j-1)!(2006-j)!(2j-1)}\\
\end{align*}

So
\begin{align*} F \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{P \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\prod_{i=1}^{2006}(\frac{1}{2}+i)}\\
&= \frac{2^{4012}2006 ! P \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)}{4013 !}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2006} \frac{(j+2006)!}{j!} \times \frac{8}{4j^2-1}  \frac{(-1)^{2007-j}}{4013 (j-1)!(2006-j)!}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2006} {2006 \choose j}{j+2006 \choose j} \times \frac{(-1)^{2007-j}8}{4j^2-1}  \frac{j}{4013}\\
\end{align*}

So finally, noticing that

\begin{align*}  \sum_{i=1}^{2006} \frac{a_i}{2i+1} = \frac{1}{2} F \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{align*}

you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2006} \frac{a_i}{2i+1} = \frac{4}{4013}\sum_{j=1}^{2006} {2006 \choose j}{j+2006 \choose j} \times \frac{(-1)^{2007-j}j}{4j^2-1}$$

which [seems](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2F4013%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7B2006%7D+%7B2006+%5Cchoose+j%7D%7Bj%2B2006+%5Cchoose+j%7D+%5Ctimes+%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5E%7B2006-j%7Dj%7D%7B4j%5E2-1%7D) to simplify into

$$\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^{2006} \frac{a_i}{2i+1} = 1-\frac{1}{4013^2}}$$

Comment: The Mathematica APP's answer is 0.998105 = 5267/5277, But I think your method is    wonderful.

Comment: Dot[
 LinearSolve[      Table[Table[1/k, {k, n, n + 2005}], {n, 2, 2007}], 
  Table[4./(2*n - 1), {n, 2, 2007}]      ],
 Table[1/k, {k, 3, 4013, 2}]
 ]

Comment: Trying this code has a warning """" LinearSolve::luc: Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix {{0.5, 0.333333, 0.25, <<2001>>, 0.000498504, 0.000498256}, <<2005>>} may contain significant numerical errors.""""

Comment: I am not sure that the computer's result is right or wrong now.

Comment: I know now, Your answer is only one symbol behind the correct answer.

Comment: The answer is 1-1/4013^2

Comment: M= the order of Matrix. M=4, the answer is 80/81; M=5, the answer is 120/120; M=6, the answer is 168/169. So I guess you are right. YOU WIN THE COMPUTER Algorithm !!!

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: This is MMA answer ：0.9981049885973334`; 1-1/4013^2=0.9999999379042781.

Comment: @NIhts__97 Yes, there was a sign mistake. This seems to be correct now !